# Avoid unnecessary call to api using react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Says we have 2 pages, the main page is for a list of books, then the second page is for the book detail. Why we should call the api again when the user navigate back from book detail? We could just reuse the same books state.

What condition I have to check in page 1 to avoid extra call?

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchBooks(getUserId())
}
```

Comment: you would check the result of that call and only call it if it's null.  for example if (this.props.books === null) { this.props.fetchBooks(getUserId()) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `componentWillMount` function, you can check the state of your `books` prop before making the API call.

The code below will only make the API call if the `books` prop is `null`(i.e. only the first time)

```
componentWillMount() {
  if (this.props.books === null) { 
    this.props.fetchBooks(getUserId()) 
  }
}
```

The downside is that if new books are added while the user is on the book detail page, when they navigate back, the new books will not get loaded. You may need further logic to handle this depending on your use case.

Comment: how can a new book be added when the user is on detail page?

Comment: A book could be added by another user. Unless only a single user will be using this app?